# Stripe payment PHP: Issues related to expiry date of live card and telling correct CVC number wrong for other live card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to replace my current payment system with Stripe in PHP website. Currently I am using stripe lib version as 1.18.0 My PHP version is 5.3.8.
To create Stripe Token I am passing credit card number, expiry month and year and CVC number of the card to stripe. I have tested my PHP code in stripe test mode using stripe test public and private key. I have used the test credit card number that stripe has provided. The strip payment system has worked perfectly in test mode. Now I have switched to Strip Payment Live Mode using Strips Live public and secrete keys. I have tested my 3 live credit card on Stripe of type Visa, MasterCard and AmericanExpress.

Following my observations and issues that I faced. Please help me on it.

Out of the above three cards Only AmericanExpress cards payment transactions went successful.

But for MasterCard I got the error for it as "Failed: Your card was declined.". I have read about reasons of declined on stripe site. and tried on different days still every time my mastercard was declined by Stripe.

I tried my visa credit card and I got the error for it as "Failed: Your card's security code is incorrect." In case of Visa credit Card I am 100% sure that I have entered all the credentials (i.e. card number, expiry month / year and CVC)  correctly. Then still I surprised that how Stripe is replying with "Failed: Your card's security code is incorrect." for all the transactions.

For AmericanExpress credit card all transactions went successful but I got surprised when I put wrong expiry month and year of past i.e. 01/2015 for AmericanExpress credit card and stripe has done the transaction successfully. I was expecting an error that "Invalid expiry month and year" or something else with wrong expiry date from stripe. How this has happened? Did I missed anything in code? As I made the coding as it is as following the documentation and examples given on stripe site.

I also surprised when I checked my credit card expiry date information on Stripe Dashboard in payment section. Where the expiry date for the cards is mentioned as in the year of 2032 which is completely wrong and not matching with the expiry date mentioned on my all three credit cards respectively.

Note: Please note that I have enabled the "Decline: Charges that fail CVC verification." setting in Stripe Dashboard in Stripe settings.

Please guide me on above issues and let me know why this is happening. Did I miss to do any setting in stripe dashboard or I am missing any code in PHP. I have followed the examples whose links have been given on Documentation page in Example section. The link is as follows https://gist.github.com/boucher/1750375
Please advise.

Comment: We noticed the expiry issue, too. We contacted our Stripe support rep, they said that they send the expiry date to the bank, and it's their choice whether to check it or not.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you Sir for your reply! Do you have any idea what going wrong with my visa card I am entering all the correct information still its keep on throwing error as "Failed: Your card's security code is incorrect." I am damn sure that I am entering the correct info of visa card. The strange thing is that the same mastercard and visa card works perfectly on my old payment system. Please advise.

Comment: We've been using Stripe for about a year and have never gotten any erroneous CVC errors like that.

Comment: @Barmar  When I checked my credit card expiry date information on Stripe Dashboard in payment section which is completely wrong and not matching with the expiry date mentioned on my all three credit cards respectively. Have you faced such type of issue?

Comment: Stripe doesn't know the actual expiry date of the cards, that's held by the banks. The dashboard just shows whatever you submitted. Stripe sends the data to the bank, and the bank tells them whether it's valid or not. If the bank ignores the submitted expiry date, Stripe has no way of knowing anything's wrong.

Comment: @Barmar But sir in my case I am entering either right or wrong expiry date none of the date is being shown on stripe dash board. The stripe dash board showing some futuristic wrong month and year for the card which are not matches with either actual expiry month and year of card or entered expiry month and year. One more strange thing I noticed about my American Express card that I did two successful transaction with it and for each transaction stripe has shown different expiry month and year. Which is neither matches with actual expiry date not entered expiry date. Please let me kno your view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72137/discussion-between-param-ganak-and-barmar).